# can't access elements on ebay website via javascript on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i have a chrome extension that retrieve all orders from an ebay orders page,
it worked great in the last month, but now all the sudden cant access some elements.

let elGridComp = document.getElementsByClassName("table-grid-component");
    let elOrders = elGridComp[0].childNodes[2].childNodes; //elOrders has all elements(105 in the example)

elOrders[0].getAttribute("class");//works

elOrders[2].getAttribute("class");//throw exception

for example, elOrders 0,1,3,5  will return the class attribure, but 2, 4 and 7 will throw an exception
Uncaught TypeError: elOrders[i].getAttribute is not a function.
attached photo shows some of the first elements in elOrders
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error message means `elOrders[2]` doesn't have getAttribute function which can happen if that node is not an HTML element but a text node (Chrome's devtools doesn't show such nodes if it's all whitespace, [crbug.com/823106](https://crbug.com/823106)) or a comment node.

The solution is to use `children` as it returns only elements unlike `childNodes` which returns all types of nodes.

P.S. use devtools to set a breakpoint and inspect the actual contents of the data. You can even select a part of an expression and hover the mouse to see its value, for example if you select `elOrders[i]` you will see its properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
the issue was that ebay added empty elements between the orders, dont understand why would they do that, buy once i created a function that removes all empty elements (length = 0) elOrders worked as before.

Comment: Can you explain how do i debug this? its a chrome extension , is there some tool to use?
debug would have saved me alot of time lol.
Thanks

Comment: It's the built-in browser devtools. See a [tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+content+script+chrome+extension+in+chrome) if needed.